# focus is not moving to other li element except first li

Tags: html, css, html-lists, tabindex

I have below `ul` and `li` element

```html
<div tabindex="0">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">link1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">link2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">link3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">link4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

On press of tab, focus is moving to the parent div which is having tabindex=0 but on next tab focus is on first `li` element but in the next tab it is not moving to the other `li` element .

Comment: but when i mouse hover on first li element then with tab other lement get focus

Comment: Working absolutely fine! Can you reproduce the issue ??

Comment: Yes, it's working fine with your code.

Comment: That's the desired effect. Because `hover` and `focus` are 2 different states

Comment: Works fine as others have said and additionally the focus isn't in the `li` elements but in `a` elements

Comment: yes i am able to reproduce it .Actually all this links are in footer .when in mobile view focus shifting to the div which is having tab index =0 the inner div is opeing and i want to move through tabbing all thsese li